# Vim: no highlighting at startup

Tags: vim

I am using vim together with NERDTree and MiniBufExplorer. My colorscheme is peaksea. If I start vim, no syntax is highlighted in the first buffer. The other buffers have syntax highlighted. I have "syntax enable" in my vimrc. If I type :edit the syntax gets highlighted. So I tried

```
autocmd VimEnter * edit
```

but still nothing is highlighted. Did anyone encounter a similar problem or has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: For all filetypes, or specific ones?

Comment: An interesting question is: "How does vim know the filetype"?  In that first buffer, are you reading a file with anything in it first?  With a known extension? Does the syntax have any obvious markers like `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: For every filetype. I open vim without any files specified, so it just opens the buffer it had open the last time I closed it. I assume vim knows the filetype by its extension, at least when typing :edit it works.

Comment: Could you show us your `~/.vimrc`, please?

Comment: The .vimrc I am using is split in different files, but basically I am using this setup: [link](https://github.com/amix/vimrc)

Comment: Doesn't help. Anyway, I don't see how this could be related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I remapped F12 to redo my syntax highlighting in case it gets messed up:

```
nnoremap <F12> :syntax sync fromstart<cr>
```

Maybe you can just run it as an autocmd event in your vimrc based on reading a new buffer?

```
autocmd BufReadPost * :syntax sync fromstart
```